# How to check if function is differentiable on ${\rm I\!R}$?

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

The problem is:
$$ f(x)=\left \{ a\sin \frac{\pi x}{3}+b, x\leq1 ;\quad \ln x, x>1 
\right \}$$
I have to find **a** and **b**

I've googled to find out more about this example and I've seen the following formula which should get me to my result:

$$\lim_{n\to\ 1}\frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0}$$

But this doesn't help since a I have to get my result. This formula just tell's me if the function is differentiable or not and I have to find the **a** and **b**

The results that have been given to me are the following:
[image]

Comment: Presumably, you have to find $a,b$ so that $f$ is differentiable?

Comment: Well yes, I believe this is the appropriate formulation... I need to get somehow two equations to get my a and b but How do I do that. Should I just try some separate limits..?

Comment: I've got some results I equalized limx, x->1+ and limx, x->1- with f(x0) and got that a=0 and b=0 is that correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The derivative from the right is $ln^{'}(1)=1$ and from the left You have
$f^{'}(1)=a\frac{\pi}{3}cos(\frac{\pi}{3})=a\frac{\pi}{6}$ and both must be identical so $a=\frac{6}{\pi}$. furthermore You need $f(1)=ln(1)=0$ so $\frac{6}{\pi}sin(\frac{\pi}{3})+b=\frac{6}{\pi}\sqrt{\frac{3}{4}}+b=0$ and this is $b=-3\frac{\sqrt{3}}{\pi}$.

Comment: So basically I equal two derivatives for both functions?

Comment: Exactly and finally the values of the functions themselves